# Ordering in NodeJS promises

Tags: node.js, promise

I need help with the processing order of promises in NodeJS.

I put `console.log` commands to show the order the code is executing, but I don't get the right order. I want the log in 1,2,3 order, but I get 1,3,2.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
app.get('/', async  (req, res) => {
  var device=new api(/* Host */'138.118.87.76' , '1420'/*, Timeout */);

  const data = await connect(device);
  console.log('3');
  res.json(data)
})

async function connect(device){
  await device.connect()
  .then(([login])=>login(passwords.mikrotikEquipamentUser,passwords.mikrotikEquipament))
  .then(async function(conn) {
    var c1=conn.openChannel();
    c1.write('/ip/address/print');
    console.log(1);

    c1.data // get only data here
      .subscribe(function(data) { // feeds in one result line at a time.
        console.log('2');
        return(api.resultsToObj(data))
      })
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error during processing:",err);
  });

}
```

Comment: Could you write the code in the question itself instead of a link to a screenshot? It would make it easier to understand and answer the question

Comment: why do you use `await` and .then together?

Comment: Your observable is **not** part of the promise chain.

Comment: @angrykoala thanks, i put he code now.

Comment: @Eduard i get the example code from Mikronode module, it is method for connect with mikrotik network devices. How i don't know well how to use promises i just copy and adapt the code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you explaim more about this? I'm new with promises, and never heard about observable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your `conn.openChannel` works, but the problem seems to be that `.subscribe` is calling its callback, but no Promise is returned there (api.resultsToObj(data) will not be returned either).

Assuming the subscribe will only be called **once**, a solution would be:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     c1.data // get only data here
         .subscribe(function(data) { // feeds in one result line at a time.
            console.log('2');
            resolve(api.resultsToObj(data))
         })
})
```

This way, a promise that "waits" for the callback is returned, and the await on `const data = await connect(device);` will wait until it is resolved.

Comment: Note observables *already* have a method to make a promise, that would correctly support error cases too.

Comment: thanks, this works well for the ordering, but the resolve(api.resultsToObj(data)) is not returning the data, I print his content after the console.log('2') and the content is here